# One button for on/off of Raspberry Pi 4, still using i2c

Tags: pi-4, power-management

I can't find any additional information online, so I'll try to ask it directly. I would like to put the Raspberry Pi 4 (with Lineage OS) in a case and be able to turn it on and off using just one button. Powering down is easy, but waking up is not.

I'm also using an AMP HAT, which utilizes the I2C lines. The problem is, that the GPIO3, which would be capable of waking up the Pi from Halt, is also used for I2C (terrible design decision to put the wake pin on GPIO3 btw...).

My next idea was to use a switch with two separate connections. One would pull down a GPIO for shutdown and another for waking up. But again, GPIO3 is used for I2C, pressing the button would probably interfere with I2C. If RUN and GLOBAL_EN are grounded when the OS runs, it just tun off everything. So it can't be used in the same switch.

Is there any additional way of waking up the Pi without unplugging it?

Comment: "
The problem is, that the GPIO3, which would be capable of waking up the Pi from Halt, is also used for I2C (terrible design decision to put the wake pin on GPIO3 btw...)." It is actually a good idea; what problems do you ACTUALLY have? NOTE this does NOT turn ANYTHING off - just shuts the OS down the SOC continues to run which is why restart works.

Comment: GPIO3 is also I2C. So if you are using I2C in your project, GPIO3 is not available as GPIO anymore and thereby also not for waking up. At least not without possible interference.

Comment: The solution for my problem would be Wake from Halt using GPIO different from 3.

Comment: If you want something other than GPIO3 you are out of luck because this is coded into the video core.

Comment: You can use GPIO3 for restart even if you are also using I²C. Have you ACTUALLY tried it?

Comment: the only solution is two switches - though a double switch wouldn't be two bad, sure, you'd briefly ground the i2c clock, but, what effect would that actually have when you're shutting down anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> *"if you are using I2C in your project, GPIO3 is not available as GPIO"*.

Well, yeah... there's a reason for that, and it's b/c GPIO3 has a pullup connected on the board - which as you know is necessary for I2C.

If you were running RPi OS (instead of *Lineage OS*), this would be an easy problem to solve; i.e. just use a different set of pins for I2C.

As it is, most of us here have **no experience** with *Lineage OS*, and we're not inclined to spend a lot of time researching it to learn enough to try to help you.

My suggestion is to install RPi OS, and learn how to overcome this issue *natively*. Then perhaps, with your knowledge of *Lineage OS*, you can apply what you've learned there.

Comment: How to overcome this issue natively? Wake up by GPIO3 is hardcoded in the bootloader. And I2C with Pin 5 is used by the Amp-HAT.

Comment: @MaxPower: If GPIO3 is hardcoded in the bootloader, then AFAIK the "*native*" way won't help you.  I ***suspect*** that you have fundamental diffs in your chosen OS that are incompatible with RPi OS... e.g. the `device tree`, and all of the overlays that are applied thereto.

Comment: @Seamus can you actually explain how to achieve what the OP wants, assuming Raspberry Pi OS, because it's NOT possible. You say "use a different set of pins for I2C" ... so, that would entail hardware modification to the AMP HAT. Or did I miss something from the question or this answer? See, I want the same thing. I MUST use GPIO2/3 for I2C because my HAT uses those pins for I2C - but I also want to use a single button for "poweroff"/on (yes, I know it's not actually power off, hence the `"`)

Comment: @JaromandaX: If you say it's not possible, then perhaps it's not.

Comment: @Seamus - that's not what I said - I was sort of hoping it was!